# Parsing dictionary from GAE python to create marker objects in javascript / GMaps api

Tags: google-app-engine, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm not really after a specific answer, but pointed in the right direction.

I've got some coorindates and names as a dictionary stored in a list sitting in GAE using python. I want to create some marker objects in google maps with this data. The problem is, I'm not quite sure how to go about this in a good way.

This is an example of the data.
[{'name': 'derp', 'lat': 123456, 'lng': 1234567}, {'name': 'hurp', 'lat': 431234123, 'lng': 453453453}]

I was thinking that I would convert this list dict to something javascript-friendly, insert it directly into my javascript code as a variable and then for a for-loop over the following function with my list.

```
function addMarker(lat, lng, name){
        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: point,
                                             map: map,
                                             title: name
                                            });

}
```

Clear as mud?

I'm almost certainly looking in the wrong direction, so throw any ideas at me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON is very javascript friendly. You can dump your dictionary in a JSON string and insert it in your javascript as you suggest in your question.
Or you create a GAE webservice to request the JSON data in your client. This is an easy option, If you are familiair with jquery / ajax and a preferred solution if the client can change the request.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using templates, passing your array of markers to the template (in a binding named 'markers'), and then doing something like

```
{% for marker in markers %}
  addMaker({{marker.lat}},{{marker.long}},'{{marker.name}}');
{% endfor %}
```

should do what you need.

Comment: I went with this solution, it was a bit easier for me to understand and implement. Will look at JSON more closely later